# Node.JS not appending string weird bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function getStatementValue(view, statement){ // vars "@extends('parentview') ", 'extends'
    var parentname = "";

    view.replace(new RegExp(/\B@\w+\('([^(')\W]+)'\)\s/, 'm'), function(occurance){
        parentname = occurance.replace('@' + statement + '(\'', '')
            .replace('\')', "");
        console.log(parentname) // parentview
        console.log(parentname + 'test') // testntview <- unexpected result
    });

    return parentname;
}
```

I've got no clue to how that result is appearing.
when I add the string as shown in console.log, it replaces the string from the beginning, almost like it's re-assigning the memory space. Is this supposed to be happening? How do I return the correct `parentviewtest` result?

Comment: your code, as is, with those arguments (I assume that's what you mean in the comment on the top line) results in `parentname` never changing - i.e. `function(occurance)` doesn't seem to get called, ever -

Comment: @JaromandaX fixed the arg, just added a space. It is getting called because console.log is being fired but my concern is why is the string appending from the start and replacing the string?

Comment: it's not ... my guess is parentname is "parentview\r"  before you add `test` ... so, it becomes `parentview\rtest` which outputs as `testntview`

Comment: Interesting, but why would that be happening from the + operator?

Comment: it's not ... it's your `view` argument, I bet there is no "space" at the end of the line, I bet there's a "\r\n" there

Comment: @JaromandaX I just understood as you posted that comment, off to solve it haha

Comment: Side note: `[^(')\W]` seems a bit redundant. Is it any different than `\w`?

Comment: @JoeFrambach, Thanks, fixed that. Gotta love stackoverflow hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parentname = occurance.replace('@' + statement + '(\'', '')
     .replace('\')', "").trim();
```

Solved it by adding a `.trim()` to the string modification. My input included invisible \r and \n characters that I was unaware of.

Thanks to @JaromandaX for spotting that out